# how to insert html text in SAS email body

Tags: html, email, sas, ods

Hi Could you all please help me in inserting HTML Text with font options in SAS Email. I tried the below code but without proc report in body the output is blank.

```
enter code here

/*options errorabend;*/
%MACRO mail_send1();
```

filename mymail email from="someone@email.com"

```
to=("someone@email.com")

subject="Territory Sales"
 content_type="Text/HTML"
  attach = ("/sasdata/sas_codes/NewSales/SalesValid.xls"         Content_type="application/excel");
 ods _all_  close;
 ODS ESCAPECHAR='^'; 
ods html body=mymail  style=minimal;

title j=left  font = verdana height=10pt  color=black
title "Good Morning, ^{newline 2}

Attached is the Aug 2016 Sales Report. ^{newline 2}


Thanks and Regards, ^{newline 2} 

^{style [Font_weight=bold FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=Navy ] Santh S}      ^{newline 1}
^{style [Font_weight=bold FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=Navy ] Business Analyst}     ^{newline 1} 
^{style [ FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=black ] GR Team} ^{newline 1} 
^{style [Font_weight=bold FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=Navy ] Client Analytics }      ^{newline 1}
^{style [Font_weight=bold FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=Navy ] UnrbaPro}      ^{newline 1}
^{style [ FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=black ] UBSC, Dekhi 400019, INDIA}     ^{newline 2}

^{style [ Font_weight=bold FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=black ]  TEL        } 
^{style [ FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=black ]  + 91 40 4090 1000} ^{newline 1}
^{style [ Font_weight=bold FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=black ]  INTERNAL  } 

^{style [ FONT=(verdana,8Pt) color=black ] someone@email.com} ^{newline 5}"
```

;

```
proc report data=prod_list;
where type='XSell';
column (odr );
quit;

ods html close;
ods _all_ close;

enter code here
```

Thanks in advance, I need the only text part with formating but dont want to include any proc report.

Comment: Does it work if you don't include the formatting?

Comment: Hi Joe, I need the formatting of text too. with font font size and color for the text

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following SAS code in order to send email message with HTML body:

```
filename mymail email type='text/html' to="john.doe@stackoverflow.com" from="john.doe@stackoverflow.com" sender="john.doe@stackoverflow.com" subject="Hello, World";
data _NULL_;
file mymail;
    put '<font size=15>Hello, World!</font>';
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Alex.
and how to add more formatting to text like font color, font, underline etc. is the html coding will work here?